# How to generate and manually insert a uniqueidentifier in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to manually create a new user in my table but am finding it impossible to generate a "UniqueIdentifier" type without the code throwing an exception...

Here is my example:

```
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
SET @id = NEWID()

INSERT INTO [dbo].[aspnet_Users]
           ([ApplicationId]
           ,[UserId]
           ,[UserName]
           ,[LoweredUserName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[FirstName]
           ,[IsAnonymous]
           ,[LastActivityDate]
           ,[Culture])
     VALUES
           ('ARMS'
           ,@id
           ,'Admin'
           ,'admin'
           ,'lastname'
           ,'firstname'
           ,0
           ,'2013-01-01 00:00:00'
           ,'en')
GO
```

Throws this exception ->
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Failed to convert a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I am using the NEWID() method but it's not working...

http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/generate_new_guid_uniqueidentifier_in_sql_server.aspx

Comment: That should work fine - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/699d6/1

Comment: What type is your `UserID` column in table? Are you sure some other column is not `UniqueIdentifier` type where you are inserting strings? ApplicationID maybe?

Comment: The error is probably for another column, my guess is ApplicationID, what is the data type of ApplicationID?

Comment: It has the "uniqueidentifier" type, but I've read that should be used NewGuid () to generate a type "uniqueidentifier". Is that wrong?

Comment: ahhhh just ! applicationID is a uniqueidentifier to ..

Comment: thanky Vishal . Do you can answer correctly ?

Comment: I think you have another uniqueidentifier column that you are inserting a string value, such as UserID

Comment: in that case, you cannot insert 'ARMS' as ApplicationID. You need to use NEWID() for it as well. SQL Server does not have NewGuid().

Comment: You above code is absolutely fine. Error is actually on another field. So, again check the Data Type of Each fields. Im guessing that, you are using UniqueIdentifier on other than the ID column.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

ApplicationId must be of type `UniqueIdentifier`.  Your code works fine if you do:

```
DECLARE @TTEST TABLE
(
  TEST UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

DECLARE @UNIQUEX UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @UNIQUEX = NEWID();

INSERT INTO @TTEST
(TEST)
VALUES
(@UNIQUEX);

SELECT * FROM @TTEST
```

Therefore I would say it is safe to assume that `ApplicationId` is not the correct data type.

Answer (score 4):

Kindly check Column ApplicationId datatype in Table aspnet_Users , ApplicationId column datatype should be uniqueidentifier .

****Your parameter order is passed wrongly ,
Parameter @id should be passed as first argument, but in your script it is placed in second argument.***.*

So error is raised..

Please refere sample script:

```
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
SET @id = NEWID()
Create Table #temp1(AppId uniqueidentifier)

insert into #temp1 values(@id)

Select * from #temp1

Drop Table #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your column data type should be unique identifier
And you are using the correct order when inserting values

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[aspnet_Users]
([ApplicationId],[UserId],[UserName],[LoweredUserName],[LastName]
,[FirstName],[IsAnonymous],[LastActivityDate],[Culture])
VALUES ('ARMS',NEWID(),'Admin','admin','lastname','firstname,0
,'2013-01-01 00:00:00','en')
```