# Insert record with uniqueidentifier column

Tags: sql-server, identifier

I want to insert new records into a table called `[dbo].[Local]` that has these columns:

```
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Component] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Language] [varchar](10) NULL,
[IsText] [bit] NULL,
[key] [varchar](100) NULL,
[value] [varchar](max) NULL,
```

And the primary key called [id] is key clustered as:

```
[id] ASC) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The insert command is like shown below. But how can I set a value for the `[id]` column because I get an error when I try to enter the value in the `[id]` column.
How can I insert value to this field automatically?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Local] ([id], [Component], [Language], [IsText], [key],[value])
VALUES (00000000-0000-0000-000-00000000000, 
        'Transport.Web', 'en', 1, 'ResourceTypeEmployee', 'TypeOffice')
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The value '00000000-0000-0000-000-00000000000' is just an example in the query. What i actually want is to enter a random value in the uniqueidentifier automatically each time i add a new record with an insert into statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate and manually insert a uniqueidentifier in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274276/how-to-generate-and-manually-insert-a-uniqueidentifier-in-sql-server)

Comment: Select newid(), it will return random for you

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the value you want to insert to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`-type:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Local]
    (         
    [id],
    [Component],
    [Language],
    [IsText],
    [key],
    [value])
VALUES
    (
     CAST('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), 
     'Transport.Web',
     'en',
     1,
     'ResourceTypeEmployee',
     'TypeOffice'
    )
```

For inserting a new random `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` you can use `NEWID()`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Local]
    (         
    [id],
    [Component],
    [Language],
    [IsText],
    [key],
    [value])
VALUES
    (
     NEWID(), 
     'Transport.Web',
     'en',
     1,
     'ResourceTypeEmployee',
     'TypeOffice'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

the insert select face :

```
INSERT INTO foo 
([UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_col] ,[col2] , [...]) 
select NEWID() , [bar.selected_col1] , [...] from bar 
where (condition)
```